# Build an Authenticating SMTP Client

Tags: code-golf

The basic parts of [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) can be implemented in surprising little code. I was able to build an example SMTP client that works with Gmail and Amazon SES [in about 320 characters using PHP](https://gist.github.com/Xeoncross/2002233#file-smtp_mail-php).

Your task is to implement an SMTP client that can send UTF-8 email from at least 2 major providers listed here:

- Gmail
- Yahoo!
- Live/Hotmail
- Postmark
- Amazon SES

Keep in mind that most require SSL support. Some SMTP services (like Amazon) require different SMTP Auth and From addresses. Your function can take input for the actual data transmitted. After all, it woudn't make sense to hard-code anything into the transport layer.

- SMTP User
- SMTP Password
- SMTP Host
- SMTP Port
- DATA (message)
- From email
- To email

Sample DATA (message)

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?VGVzdCBFbWFpbA==?=\r\n
To: <him@gmail.com>\r\n
From: <you@gmail.com>\r\n
MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n
PGgxPlRlc3QgRW1haWw8L2gxPjxwPkhlbGxvIFRoZXJlITwvcD4=\r\n.
```

#### In Summary

1. Build an SMTP client that can send email through at least two of the services above.
2. Accepts the seven inputs needed to form a valid SMTP Auth request (above). (Might only need six inputs if you combine the "From" and "SMTP User" inputs).
3. Use as few characters as posible.

Comment: Welcome to CodeGolf.SE! Our FAQ requires that every challenge have a *"An objective primary winning criterion"*, and you need to indicate what it is; [code-golf] (i.e. fewest source characters) is the most common but there are others. Please have a look at some well received contests to see what kind of specification is usual.

Comment: @dmckee, thanks! I assumed that "fewest source characters" was a given so I listed the other requirements above. However, I have amended the question with the [code-golf] tag. It would be great if someone with more rep could add other tags like "smtp".

Comment: -1 I (as a user, not as a mod---ignore the diamond for this message) dislike this question, because your "reference" solution doesn't display any originality---it just calls library functions to do the heavy-lifting. That's no fun! If your code actually handled the SMTP (using system-provided sockets is okay), the encryption (using system crypto primitives is okay), the base64, etc., then it'd be far more interesting to try to golf. But what you have now is basically a "which language provides the right libraries?" contest.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young, I'm not sure what to say. Using built-in language functions like `fsocketopen` is to be expected. What exactly are you looking for in an example?

Comment: Oh, I see. I see you did actually implement your own SMTP. My bad for not seeing the second file in your Gist. :-P (I retracted my downvote, BTW.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young, I suppose. However, if they include a pre-built mail client - then they automatically fail because they don't meet the first requirement of "build an SMTP client". However, I can't imagine anyone having the time to build a TLS SSL implementation - so they are welcome to use system libraries to solve this problem.

Comment: That's a fair enough explanation. As I mentioned, I removed my downvote---you seemed to have adequately clarified your question. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young, ah, now your comment makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 864 bytes

Extremely quick and dirty. Works with AWS SES and Yahoo!. Could not get it to work with Postmark (requires STARTTLS) or Gmail (requires further authentication outside of the SMTP connection).

```
import socket,ssl
from base64 import*
N=b'\x00'
U='utf-8'
E=lambda s:s.encode(U)
D=lambda b:b.decode(U)
B=lambda s:D(b64encode(E(s)))
A=lambda f,t,j,b:E('\r\n'.join(['DATA','Subject: =?UTF-8?B?{}?=','To: <{}>','From: <{}>','MIME-Version: 1.0','Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8','Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64',B(b),'','.','']).format(B(j),t,f,b))
X=lambda s,e:s.startswith(e)
def S(h,u,p,t,f,j,b):
    c,F,W=ssl.wrap_socket(socket.create_connection((h,465))),lambda m:E(m if'amazonaws'in h else'<'+m+'>'),lambda m:c.write(m+b'\r\n')
    def R(d,o=[]):
        x,y=c.read(),str(d)
        if not(X(x,E(y))or filter(lambda i:X(i,X(x,E(y))),o)):raise RuntimeError(y+' '+repr(x))
    R(220);W(b'EHLO x');R(250);W(b'AUTH PLAIN '+b64encode(N+E(u)+N+E(p)));R(235);W(b'MAIL FROM: '+F(f));R(250);W(b'RCPT TO: '+F(t));R(250);W(A(f,t,j,b));R(250,(354,));W(b'QUIT')
```

Invoke like `S(hostname, username, password, to, from_, subject, body)`

Expect bugs and changes (kind of got bored so it feels slightly half-baked).

Comment: I have a feeling you're going to be one of the new regulars ;)

Answer (score -3):

C# .NET, assuming all the proper namespaces have been imported and not counting newlines/whitespace as characters. Also, displays no output as it's used as a library function.

```
bool sm(string h, string u, string p, string r, string m) {
    try {
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Host = h;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(u, p);
        smtp.UseSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(u, r, "", m);
        return true;
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In its compressed form, the way I would code it, it'd look like this:

```
bool sm(string h, string u, string p, string r, string m) { try { SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(); smtp.Port = 587; smtp.Host = h; smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(u, p); smtp.UseSsl = true; smtp.Send(u, r, "", m); return true; } catch { return false; } }
```

Call it cheating, because of using .NET, but 266 characters. Works with major providers that allow SMTP with STARTTLS authentication on port 587. I use this for my Gmail all the time, works with Windows Live Hotmail too. Can be used either client-side OR server-side, and requires .NET 2.0 or newer (so it's compatible with pretty much every Windows machine).

Comment: Almost forgot the SSL, that's all fine and good though. I fixed it, with +20 characters.

Comment: You did not `1. Build an SMTP client`.

Comment: We will leave that for the op to decide :P As it was not said that library calls could not be used, I decline to change my code at this time.

Comment: You can use built-in functions and libraries, but you still have to build an SMTP client - not wrap one. ;)